# Is it possible to set a Tag for bluetooth and getting it later Android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Since, that I'm not able to get my local Mac Bluetooth Address, my solution was to create a a custom id, my question is very simple is their a possibility to set a Tag for Bluetooth, something like `bluetoothAdapter.setName` but it must be not visible to the users.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Do you want to set a name on your Bluetooth device but don't want that name to be visible to remote devices? Why do you want to do this and how do you want your device to appear to remote devices?

Comment: I need to do this because i want to pass a string to others pairs devices without been connected to them.